# Using codeigniter's validation on jquery ajax post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

i'm trying to validate a form using jquery, ajax and json using codeigniter's validation, this is what I've tried:

this is my controller:

```
function cadastrar(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nome', 'Nome', 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[15]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('sobrenome', 'Sobrenome', 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[15]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('senha', 'Senha', 'required|matches[confirmar]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirmar', 'Confirmação de senha', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        echo '{"mensagem": "Erro", "nome_erro": "' . form_error('nome') . '", "sobrenome_erro": "' . form_error('sobrenome') . '", "email_erro" : "' . form_error('email') . '", "senha_erro" : "' . form_error('senha') . '", "confirmar_erro" : "' . form_error('confirmar') . '" }';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '{"mensagem": "Registro com sucesso !", "nome_erro": "", "sobrenome_erro": "", "email_erro" : "", "senha_erro" : "", "confirmar_erro" : "" }';
    }
}
```

and this is my jquery function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.cadastrar_enviar').click(function(){
        var nome = $('.cadastro_nome').val();
        var sobrenome = $('.cadastro_sobrenome').val();
        var email = $('.cadastro_email').val();
        var senha = $('.cadastro_senha').val();
        var confirmar = $('.cadastro_confirmar').val();
        var mensagem = "";
        $("#loading").show();

        $.post('../index.php/usuario/cadastrar', {
            "nome" : nome,
            "sobrenome" : sobrenome,
            "email" : email,
            "senha" : senha,
            "confirmar" : confirmar
        }, function(data){          
                $('#loading').hide(500);
                $('span#nome_erro').html(data.nome_erro);
                $('span#sobrenome_erro').html(data.sobrenome_erro);
                $('span#email_erro').html(data.email_erro);
                $('span#senha_erro').html(data.senha_erro);
                $('span#confirmar_erro').html(data.confirmar_erro);
                alert(data.confirmar_erro);
                $('#mensagem_oi').html(data.mensagem).show(500);
            }, "json");
        });

    });
```

and I get nothing on errors, form_error() isn't returning anything, can anyone give me a hint? thanks

Comment: What happens if you post data to the page through an HTML form? Do you see any text?

Comment: Any reason you aren't using the jQuery [validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)? You could be validating this form with a fraction of the javascript code and without the need for AJAX....

Comment: @Madmartigan I would agree that it is better to use a jQuery  validation plugin than this. However, it is no reason that this post should be downvoted. Apologies if the downvote was for some other reason.

Comment: @user824294: It wasn't my downvote, but it doesn't matter - people may vote for any reason they like. I'd argue to you that upvotes are not for "cancelling" someone else's downvote (apologies if the upvote was for another reason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery is expecting the controller to return a json page, but the controller is responding with an ordinary html page. You should specify the output format in the header, in Codeigniter the code looks something like:

```
$this->output
->set_content_type('application/json')
->set_output(json_encode(array("mensagem"=> "Registro com sucesso !", "nome_erro"=> "", "sobrenome_erro"=> "", "email_erro" =< "", "senha_erro" => "", "confirmar_erro" => "")));
```

Look at output class: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html

This way you should see something, but I don't know if the validation will work.

Answer (score 0):

CI validation triggers on form submit.
Try to submit form.

```
$('.cadastrar_enviar').submit(function(){
});
```